# Animating an SVG ellipse path with CSS translate

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, translate

I'm kind of new to SVG animation and have been trying to animate an ellipse path in an SVG I designed using the CSS translate function as documented on CSS Tricks

Here is the svg code for the ellipse itself

```
<ellipse id="halo"  class="halo_path" transform="rotate(-71.04 448.99 166.502)" cx="449" cy="166.5" rx="63" ry="234.3" />
```

What I'm trying to do is get it to rise a couple of pixels and come down (as a loop) but when I added the CSS for the @keyframe:

```
.halo_path {
    transform: rotate(109deg);
    fill: none;
    stroke: #D9CC29;
    stroke-width: 25.0519;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    transform-origin: center;
    animation: move_halo 2s infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes move_halo {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 5px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, -10px);
    }
}
```

...what happens in that the animation works but the ellipse path becomes straight like this:
[image]

I'd really appreciate if I can get it to animate up and down but at the original angle which I designed the ellipse to look like which was like this:

[image]

PS-I'm looking to achieve this without JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the animation to a parent element so it doesn't overwrite the ellipse's transform.

```css
html, body, svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ellipse {
    transform: rotate(109deg);
    fill: none;
    stroke: #D9CC29;
    stroke-width: 25.0519;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    transform-origin: center;
}

.halo_path {
    animation: move_halo 2s infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes move_halo {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 5px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, -10px);
    }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 400">
    <g class="halo_path" >
    <ellipse cx="449" cy="166.5" rx="63" ry="234.3" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. The entire illustration that included the path was in a group so removing it from that parent group and targeting it like you suggested worked well.